# Configure hibernate (using JPA) to store Y/N for type Boolean instead of 0/1

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Can I setup JPA/hibernate to persist `Boolean` types as `Y/N`? In the database (the column is defined as `varchar2(1)`. It currently stores them as `0/1`. The database is Oracle.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The only way I've figured out how to do this is to have two properties for my class. One as the boolean for the programming API which is not included in the mapping. It's getter and setter reference a private char variable which is Y/N. I then have another protected property which is included in the hibernate mapping and it's getters and setters reference the private char variable directly.

EDIT: As has been pointed out there are other solutions that are directly built into Hibernate. I'm leaving this answer because it can work in situations where you're working with a legacy field that doesn't play nice with the built in options. On top of that there are no serious negative consequences to this approach.

Comment: I had to do something similar - I changed the type of the member from Boolean to String. In the getters and setters (which got and set Boolean) I wrote code to convert Y/N to the corresponding Boolean value.

Comment: @bernardn No, it is the better one.

Comment: Here is a better solution https://thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-tips-how-to-map-a-boolean-to-y-n/

Answer (score 152):

Hibernate has a built-in "yes_no" type that would do what you want. It maps to a CHAR(1) column in the database.

Basic mapping: `<property name="some_flag" type="yes_no"/>`

Annotation mapping (Hibernate extensions):

```
@Type(type="yes_no")
public boolean getFlag();
```

Comment: For those who are interested, there is also a "true_false" type that will store either "T" or "F".

Comment: This worked, but I could not use it because it's a hibernate specific annotation. Thanks for the answer. Might use it in a different project.

Comment: this is for hibernate 4 and later, that means for java 1.6 and later. doesent work for hibernate 3.*

Comment: @storm_buster Hibernate 4 did not exist when this answer was given. It works perfectly fine with Hibernate 3.x and java 1.5

Comment: How to put 0 or 1 then?

Comment: for varchar2 in oracle add also column definition annotation

    @Type(type="yes_no")
    @Column(columnDefinition = 'varchar2(1)')

Comment: "type" attribute doesn't exist anymore, therefore the solution is no longer valid for current hibernate version (6.*).

Answer (score 92):

This is pure JPA without using getters/setters. As of 2013/2014 it is the best answer without using any Hibernate specific annotations, but please note this solution is JPA 2.1, and was not available when the question was first asked:

```
@Entity
public class Person {    

    @Convert(converter=BooleanToStringConverter.class)
    private Boolean isAlive;    
    ...
}
```

And then:

```
@Converter
public class BooleanToStringConverter implements AttributeConverter<Boolean, String> {

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Boolean value) {        
        return (value != null && value) ? "Y" : "N";            
        }    

    @Override
    public Boolean convertToEntityAttribute(String value) {
        return "Y".equals(value);
        }
    }
```

**Edit:**

The implementation above considers anything different from character "Y", including `null`, as `false`. Is that correct? Some people here consider this incorrect, and believe that `null` in the database should be `null` in Java.

But if you return `null` in Java, it will give you a `NullPointerException` if your field is a **primitive boolean**. In other words, unless some of your fields actually use the **class Boolean** it's best to consider `null` as `false`, and use the above implementation. Then Hibernate will not to emit any exceptions regardless of the contents of the database.

And if you do want to accept `null` and emit exceptions if the contents of the database are not strictly correct, then I guess you should not accept **any** characters apart from "Y", "N" and `null`. Make it consistent, and don't accept any variations like "y", "n", "0" and "1", which will only make your life harder later. This is a more strict implementation:

```
@Override
public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Boolean value) {
    if (value == null) return null;
    else return value ? "Y" : "N";
    }

@Override
public Boolean convertToEntityAttribute(String value) {
    if (value == null) return null;
    else if (value.equals("Y")) return true;
    else if (value.equals("N")) return false;
    else throw new IllegalStateException("Invalid boolean character: " + value);
    }
```

And yet another option, if you want to allow for `null` in Java but not in the database:

```
@Override
public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Boolean value) {
    if (value == null) return "-";
    else return value ? "Y" : "N";
    }

@Override
public Boolean convertToEntityAttribute(String value) {
    if (value.equals("-") return null;
    else if (value.equals("Y")) return true;
    else if (value.equals("N")) return false;
    else throw new IllegalStateException("Invalid boolean character: " + value);
    }
```

Comment: The converter shows the idea, but is of course not working. The converter uses the possible values of `Y`, `N` and `T`. I am also not sure one should omit the case of having a null value as a result of a conversion.

Comment: @Matthias Yes, T was a typo. I fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: I had an issue using the Y/N field with JPQL and posted a followup question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39581225/unable-to-render-boolean-literal-value-when-using-attributeconverter-for-boole

Answer (score 13):

I used the concept from the answer posted by @marcg and it works great with JPA 2.1. His code wasn't quite right, so I'm posted my working implementation. This will convert `Boolean` entity fields to a Y/N character column in the database.

From my entity class:

```
@Convert(converter=BooleanToYNStringConverter.class)
@Column(name="LOADED", length=1)
private Boolean isLoadedSuccessfully;
```

My converter class:

```
/**
 * Converts a Boolean entity attribute to a single-character
 * Y/N string that will be stored in the database, and vice-versa
 * 
 * @author jtough
 */
public class BooleanToYNStringConverter 
        implements AttributeConverter<Boolean, String> {

    /**
     * This implementation will return "Y" if the parameter is Boolean.TRUE,
     * otherwise it will return "N" when the parameter is Boolean.FALSE. 
     * A null input value will yield a null return value.
     * @param b Boolean
     */
    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Boolean b) {
        if (b == null) {
            return null;
        }
        if (b.booleanValue()) {
            return "Y";
        }
        return "N";
    }

    /**
     * This implementation will return Boolean.TRUE if the string
     * is "Y" or "y", otherwise it will ignore the value and return
     * Boolean.FALSE (it does not actually look for "N") for any
     * other non-null string. A null input value will yield a null
     * return value.
     * @param s String
     */
    @Override
    public Boolean convertToEntityAttribute(String s) {
        if (s == null) {
            return null;
        }
        if (s.equals("Y") || s.equals("y")) {
            return Boolean.TRUE;
        }
        return Boolean.FALSE;
    }

}
```

This variant is also fun if you love emoticons and are just sick and tired of Y/N or T/F in your database. In this case, your database column must be two characters instead of one. Probably not a big deal.

```
/**
 * Converts a Boolean entity attribute to a happy face or sad face
 * that will be stored in the database, and vice-versa
 * 
 * @author jtough
 */
public class BooleanToHappySadConverter 
        implements AttributeConverter<Boolean, String> {

    public static final String HAPPY = ":)";
    public static final String SAD = ":(";

    /**
     * This implementation will return ":)" if the parameter is Boolean.TRUE,
     * otherwise it will return ":(" when the parameter is Boolean.FALSE. 
     * A null input value will yield a null return value.
     * @param b Boolean
     * @return String or null
     */
    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Boolean b) {
        if (b == null) {
            return null;
        }
        if (b) {
            return HAPPY;
        }
        return SAD;
    }

    /**
     * This implementation will return Boolean.TRUE if the string
     * is ":)", otherwise it will ignore the value and return
     * Boolean.FALSE (it does not actually look for ":(") for any
     * other non-null string. A null input value will yield a null
     * return value.
     * @param s String
     * @return Boolean or null
     */
    @Override
    public Boolean convertToEntityAttribute(String s) {
        if (s == null) {
            return null;
        }
        if (HAPPY.equals(s)) {
            return Boolean.TRUE;
        }
        return Boolean.FALSE;
    }

}
```

Comment: Is the unboxing 'b.booleanValue()' necessary?

Comment: Except for `NULL` property for `NULL` database value, this answer doesn't provide any value add over @MarKG answer. Best to captured that difference as a comment.

Comment: You're 5 years too late guy

Answer (score 2):

To even do better boolean mapping to Y/N, add to your hibernate configuration:

```
<!-- when using type="yes_no" for booleans, the line below allow booleans in HQL expressions: -->
<property name="hibernate.query.substitutions">true 'Y', false 'N'</property>
```

Now you can use booleans in HQL, for example:

```
"FROM " + SomeDomainClass.class.getName() + " somedomainclass " +
"WHERE somedomainclass.someboolean = false"
```

Comment: This is global. Not adequate for singular properties.

Answer (score 0):

To do it in a generic JPA way using getter annotations, the example below works for me with Hibernate 3.5.4 and Oracle 11g. Note that the mapped getter and setter (`getOpenedYnString` and `setOpenedYnString`) are private methods. Those methods provide the mapping but all programmatic access to the class is using the `getOpenedYn` and `setOpenedYn` methods.

```
private String openedYn;

@Transient
public Boolean getOpenedYn() {
  return toBoolean(openedYn);
}

public void setOpenedYn(Boolean openedYn) {
  setOpenedYnString(toYesNo(openedYn));
}

@Column(name = "OPENED_YN", length = 1)
private String getOpenedYnString() {
  return openedYn;
}

private void setOpenedYnString(String openedYn) {
  this.openedYn = openedYn;
}
```

Here's the util class with static methods `toYesNo` and `toBoolean`:

```
public class JpaUtil {

    private static final String NO = "N";
    private static final String YES = "Y";

    public static String toYesNo(Boolean value) {
        if (value == null)
            return null;
        else if (value)
            return YES;
        else
            return NO;
    }

    public static Boolean toBoolean(String yesNo) {
        if (yesNo == null)
            return null;
        else if (YES.equals(yesNo))
            return true;
        else if (NO.equals(yesNo))
            return false;
        else
            throw new RuntimeException("unexpected yes/no value:" + yesNo);
    }
}
```