# Differerence between hibernate types: boolean, yes_no, true_false

Tags: java, database, hibernate, types

When to use each? To what do they map in the database?

Comment: Have a look at:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1154833/configure-hibernate-using-jpa-to-store-y-n-for-type-boolean-instead-of-0-1

Answer (score 11, accepted):

from Hibernate:
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core.old/reference/en/html_single/#mapping-types-basictypes

> *boolean*, *yes_no*  and *true_false* are
>   all alternative encodings for a Java
>   boolean or java.lang.Boolean.

Answer (score 12):

Follow `true_false`, if you like `T`/`F` at database level. Otherwise, use `yes_no`, it will give you `Y`/`N` in the database.

By the way, got to know that there are some issues with these, which result in unexpected value. For example [here](http://coding.derkeiler.com/Archive/Java/comp.lang.java.databases/2007-03/msg00056.html) and [here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/218458/Object-Relational-Mapping/java/Mapping-oracle-boolean-Java-boolean), Few seems fixed already in successive updates, though.