# Set boolean to javax.persistenc.Query

Tags: hibernate, jpa

We dont use hibernate propriety API.
We follow pure JPA standard API. 
How to set a boolean value as parameter to JPQL query?(javax.persistenc.Query)
 the following is not working

```
    @NamedQuery(name = "Employee.getEmployeeByState", query = "select employee.id From Employee employee where employee.state=:inputState")


    Query getEmployeesExcluded = entityManager.createNamedQuery("Employee.getEmployeeByState");
    getEmployeesExcluded .setParameter("inputState", Boolean.FALSE);
```

Comment: when i hard core the query its working     @NamedQuery(name = "Employee.getEmployeeByState", query = "select employee.id From Employee employee where employee.state=1")

Comment: Define "not working". Precisely.

Comment: Its returning all entries irrespective to employee.state TRUE/FALSE

Comment: Post the code of the entity and the table definition. And a test case.

Comment: what is the type in Java and on the DB table of state?

Answer (score -1):

The problem could happen because in your entity you should have the `state` attribute as `boolean`, but in your database it should be `tinyint` or `int` or something like that (since we don't know your entity I am assuming that), so probably you should use a `typeConverter`:

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name = "Employee.getEmployeeByState", query = "select employee.id From Employee employee where employee.state=:inputState")
public class Employee implements Serializable {

    @TypeConverter(name="intToBoolean", dataType=Integer.class, objectType=Boolean.class)
    private boolean state;

    //getters and setters
}
```

[here](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/toplink/TLJPA/a_typeconverter.htm#TLJPA571) you can find more information about that annotation.

**EDIT:**

Or you can implement your own converter, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4160743/5602069), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8038939/5602069) and [this](https://codingexplained.com/coding/java/hibernate/hibernate-mapping-smallint-tinyint-int-column-to-boolean)

Comment: Why are you referring to a Toplink annotation when the questioner is using Hibernate?

Comment: @AlanHay you're right, I did not notice it was a Toplink annotation... I just edit the answer ;)