# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "deleted" is of type smallint but expression is of type boolean

Tags: postgresql, java-8, liquibase

I'm trying to save boolean value as 0 as false and 1 as true in postrges database using below configurations,

**liquibase\changes\001.add-delete-column.json**

```
 {
  "databaseChangeLog": [
    {
      "changeSet": {
        "id": "001-add-delete-colum",
        "author": "equity-deal",
        "changes": [
          {
            "addColumn": {
              "tableName": "TABLE_NAME",
              "columns": [
                {
                  "column": {
                    "name": "DELETED",
                    "type": "SMALLINT",
                    "constraints": {
                      "nullable": false
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

My domain object is of type boolean but value I defined json as BIGINT. Ideally I'm expecting value to be stored as either 0 or 1 for false/true conditions defined domain object.

**Domain Object**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class ExampleClass {

    private Long id;

    private boolean deleted;
}
```

When execute above code ending up with below exception

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "deleted" is of type smallint but expression is of type boolean
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
  Position: 159
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2440)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2183)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:308)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:441)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:365)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:143)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PgPreparedStatement.java:120)
```

How can I achieve saving 0 or 1 for false or true?

Comment: Why define the column as `bigint` when you want to store a `boolean` - you should use a `boolean` then? Would you use a `long` variable in Java for a `boolean` value?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Defining boolean is saving true of false but not 0 or 1

Comment: Then you need to define your variable in Java as `long` as well. The data types have to match. `0` and `1` are not valid boolean values. Neither in Postgres nor in Java. But if you use a `boolean` in Java, you should use a `boolean` in the database as well.

Comment: we have constraint not tomodify domain object(java)

Comment: The data type of your Java variable should match the datatype in the database. If you need a boolean in Java, then the obvious and only logical choice is `boolean` in the database as well.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name So if I want to save 0 or 1, how can I achieve it?

Comment: `0` and `1` are integers. So you need an `integer` column in the table and an `int` variable in Java. But as your Java variable is defined as `boolean` you should **really** be using `boolean` in the database as well. Why do you insist on storing that value in a column that doesn't match the type of your Java variable? **Always** use the correct data types in the database that match your Java variables. Store `LocalDate` values in a `date` column, store `BigDecimal` in a `numeric` column, store `String` values in a `text` column and store `boolean` values in a `boolean` column.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name agreed to you're comment, trying to approach this solution for my requirement https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4160743/is-it-possible-to-do-type-conversion-from-boolean-to-yes-no-in-pure-jpa, thanks for immediate responses.