# Mapping the primitive boolean to Character Y/N with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Configure hibernate (using JPA) to store Y/N for type Boolean instead of 0/1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1154833/configure-hibernate-using-jpa-to-store-y-n-for-type-boolean-instead-of-0-1)

Is it possible to map the primitive boolean to a Y/N character with hibernate?

Comment: hibernate type yes_no generates the Boolean type as opposed to the boolean type.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom [UserType](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/usertype/UserType.html)

With the UserType you can create any kind of mapping you want.