# JPA String to boolean when reading from database

Tags: java, jpa

In the database we store a value which is "Y" or "N" and is of type varchar. However, in my model class for example say in "Employee" I have a field corresponding to that value which is: a boolean for example boolean isManager.

If I make the field in the class as String it all works fine. However, I want to keep it boolean. What can be done here? Is there a way in JPA to tell it to convert to 1 or 0 or true or false based on "Y" and "N" values?

Comment: Can't you change the data type of your column to `char(1)`? You should be able to map the boolean field to that column then.

Comment: something like `boolean isManager=rs.getString("manager").equals("Y")`?

Comment: If you are willing to use provider specific feature and are using Hibernate as the JPA provider, [UserType](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/usertype/UserType.html) is the way to go.

Comment: Seems there are JPA specific annotations to achieve the behavior of Hibernate UserType: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.6/reference/en/html/listeners.html#d0e3069

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much depends on your class and how you use it. If your class is a POJO with no logic, you can do without EntityListeners and with JPA only, by having simply proxying your private `manager` String field with a **transient** boolean field, eg. :

```
...
private String manager;
private transient boolean managing;

...
public boolean isManaging {
    return "Y".equals(manager);
}

public void setManaging(boolean managing) {
    this.managing = managing;
    this.manager = managing ? "Y" : "N";
}
```

with no getter/setter for `manager`, or private ones if you care (or annotate your methods instead of your fields).

Better still would be to have your `manager` field as an enum instead of a String with the JPA annotation `@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)`.

**EDIT**: Also, have a look at [Configure hibernate (using JPA) to store Y/N for type Boolean instead of 0/1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1154833/configure-hibernate-using-jpa-to-store-y-n-for-type-boolean-instead-of-0-1?rq=1)

Answer (score -1):

```
String str = "Y";//or else "N"
boolean isManager = (str.equals("Y")) ? true : false;
```

Comment: `boolean isManager = str.equals("Y");` ? :)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I am absolutely correct.

Comment: ? is also called ternary operator

Comment: ternary is from latin *ternarius* itself from *terni* which means three at once and the so called ternary operator was introduced in *an effort to write terse*, ie. less verbose, codes. By all means do make a liberal use of it but having statements like `(...) ? true : false;` will raise more than my sole eyebrows.

Comment: @TheGreat: you may be right, but the expression from okiharaherbst is absolutely sufficient, the equals already returns true or false, so the tenary operator is superficial and contrary to clean code IMHO