# Field not populating from database

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

**database table**

```
CREATE TABLE WIES.DEPARTMENT
(
    DEPT_ID               integer  NOT NULL 
        GENERATED BY DEFAULT 
        AS IDENTITY (
            START WITH 100,
            INCREMENT BY 1),
    DEPT_NME              varchar(20) ,
    SEQUENCE_NO           integer ,
    ACTIVE_IND            char(1)  DEFAULT 'Y'
);
```

**entity class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DEPARTMENT", schema = "WIES")
public class Department implements JpaObjectWithName, Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "DEPT_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer           departmentId;

    @Column(name = "SEQUENCE_NO")
    private int               sequence;

    @Column(name = "DEPT_NME")
    @Size(max = 20, message = "error.department.name.length")
    private String            name;

    @Transient
    private boolean           active;

    public Integer getDepartmentId()
    {
        return departmentId;
    }

    public void setDepartmentId(Integer departmentId)
    {
        this.departmentId = departmentId;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getSequence()
    {
        return sequence;
    }

    public void setSequence(int sequence)
    {
        this.sequence = sequence;
    }

    public boolean isActive()
    {
        return active;
    }

    public void setActive(boolean active)
    {
        this.active = active;
    }

    @Column(name = "ACTIVE_IND")
    public String getActiveString()
    {
        return BooleanUtils.toString(active, "Y", "N");
    }

    public void setActiveString(String activeString)
    {
        this.active = BooleanUtils.toBoolean(activeString);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return (this.name != null)
            ? this.name : super.toString();
    }

}
```

**DAO**

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Department> getDepartments()
    {
        String jql = "select a from Department a";
        Query query = entityManager.createQuery(jql
            + " order by a.sequence, a.name");
        return (List<Department>) query.getResultList();
    }
```

The generated sql statement from the console

```
2014-06-09 16:31:34,282 DEBUG [org.hibernate.SQL] - <select department0_.DEPT_ID as DEPT_ID1_9_, department0_.DEPT_NME as DEPT_NME2_9_, department0_.SEQUENCE_NO as SEQUENCE3_9_ from WIES.DEPARTMENT department0_ order by department0_.SEQUENCE_NO, department0_.DEPT_NME>
```

The select statement is missing the column `ACTIVE_IND`. How do I get that included into the select statement without adding another field in the Department class to be populated?

The reason is I would like to use the `boolean` field for a checkbox on the form, and for storing it into the database it needs to be `'Y'` or `'N'` as well as displaying `'Y'` or `'N'` in the table.

Comment: You already said it: there's no field to populate, so there's no need to read the field.

Comment: Related to your real problem: [Configure hibernate (using JPA) to store Y/N for type Boolean instead of 0/1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1154833/1065197). IMO the accepted answer is not the correct one, so read through the other answers to see what you can do.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit non-elastic, but in the annotations section before your class you can add WHERE annotation, like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DEPARTMENT", schema = "WIES")
@Where(clause = "active_ind = 'Y'" )
public class Department implements JpaObjectWithName, Serializable
{
.....
}
```

In this way, only the records which are active will be selected.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the annotation @Access(AccessType.FIELD) on your class, add the annotation @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY) on your getActiveString() method and keep the @Transient on the active field.