# Returning a boolean value in a case statement

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to return a boolean value from a case statement but the compiler is complaining about a ORA-00936: missing expression error:

```
SELECT
  CASE MYCOLUMN
     WHEN NULL THEN  true
  ELSE
       false
  END,
FROM MYTABLE;
```

I also tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT
  CASE MYCOLUMN
     WHEN NULL THEN  SELECT true
  ELSE
       SELECT false
  END,
FROM MYTABLE;
```

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: There is no boolean type in Oracle SQL. So as pointed out by juergen d, best option is to use 0 or 1 or characters.

Comment: Why do you need that?

Comment: @Multisync, that column will map to a field in my JPA entity which is of type boolean.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1154833/configure-hibernate-using-jpa-to-store-y-n-for-type-boolean-instead-of-0-1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need the `IS` operator for `NULL` checks

```
SELECT CASE WHEN MYCOLUMN IS NULL
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
       END
FROM MYTABLE;
```

Comment: can I not return a boolean literal instead of 1 or 0?

Comment: No, you can't. You can use `0` and `1` or the strings `'true'` and `'false'`

Comment: how to check boolean condition in case when

Answer (score 0):

`BOOLEAN` type is not supported in SQL. It is supported only in procedural PL/SQL