# ORA-00920: Invalid relational operator (no missing/extra parenthesis)

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have an error when I try to execute the following query and I don't understand why.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT lpad(obj.no, 4, '0') || ' - ' || obj.nom, obj.no
  FROM TABLE(objects_pkg.get_all()) obj
 WHERE obj.start_date <=
       (CASE
        WHEN util_pkg.is_date_valid(p_date => :v_start_date) ̲T̲H̲E̲N
          to_date(:v_start_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
        ELSE
          trunc(SYSDATE)
       END)
```

I checked for missing / extra parenthesis but I couldn't find any.
I tried several ways of *structuring* the `CASE` like the following but none of them worked.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT lpad(obj.no, 4, '0') || ' - ' || obj.nom, obj.no
  FROM TABLE(objects_pkg.get_all()) obj
 WHERE (CASE
         WHEN util_pkg.is_date_valid(p_date => :v_start_date) ̲T̲H̲E̲N
           CASE WHEN obj.start_date <= to_date(:v_start_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
         ELSE
          CASE WHEN obj.start_date <= trunc(SYSDATE) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
       END) = 1
```

The error is always the same and is always triggered on the first `T̲H̲E̲N̲` keyword of the first `WHEN`. I tried with and without the parenthesis, I tried to remove the `THEN` keyword and I tried a lot of things but nothing worked. The error is: `ORA-00920: Invalid relational operator`

I've also tried to change the entire where clause to the following but it didn't help.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT lpad(obj.no, 4, '0') || ' - ' || obj.nom, obj.no
  FROM TABLE(objects_pkg.get_all()) obj
 WHERE (
   (
     TRIM(:v_start_date) ̲I̲S NULL
     AND util_pkg.is_date_valid(p_date => :v_start_date)
     AND obj.start_date <= to_date(:v_start_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
   )
   OR
   (
     (
       :v_start_date IS NULL
       OR NOT util_pkg.is_date_valid(p_date => :v_start_date)
     )
     AND obj.start_date <= trunc(SYSDATE)
   )
 )
```

For the above query, the error is triggered on the first `I̲S̲` keyword within the `WHERE` clause (`TRIM(:v_start_date) I̲S̲ NULL`) but the error is still an ORA-00920.

***Note:*** `util_pkg.is_date_valid` returns a `BOOLEAN`

Comment: *@a_horse_with_no_name* It's a varchar2

Comment: *@a_horse_with_no_name* Cause the query is used in an application where you can use variables provided by the application within the queries but all the variables are varchar2

Comment: Are the package names typed correctly? For example is_date_valide... could it possibly be is_date_valid?

Comment: *@HereGoes* I changed the variable/package names cause I'm not allowed to publish the code as it is so it's just a mistake I made when I renamed the function but I fixed it anyway

Comment: Okay... I only asked because when I tried your code I got the same error... but it was only because, of course, the package names weren't valid in my schema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue is that you are not testing the value from util_pkg.is_date_valid. 
The WHEN part of the CASE statement needs to be tested against something.

```
CASE
WHEN util_pkg.is_date_valid(p_date => :v_start_date) >= ? ̲T̲H̲E̲N ...
```

Comment: `is_date_valid` returns a `BOOLEAN`.
I tried to test the result with `... = TRUE` but I get the following error: `ORA-00904: "TRUE" : Invalid indentifier`

Comment: You can't return a boolean. It'll have to be a string or integer.  BOOLEAN type is not supported in SQL. It is supported only in procedural PL/SQL.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26971453/returning-a-boolean-value-in-a-case-statement

Comment: I can't change the return type of `util_pkg.is_date_valid` cause it would break other things. In fact, `is_date_valid` only calls `to_date` on the passed argument and returns `FALSE` if an error is thrown

Comment: Can you add an overloaded function to do the same code but send back a string or integer?

Comment: I can try it but is it even possible to have an overloaded function with the same arguments?

Comment: You are right the parameters are too close.  Just make another function with a different name but does the same code and returns a string or integer.

Comment: Or if you can't create functions, define one inline using a `with function as` clause (requires 12c).