# Use boolean value in HQL

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a `product` class with attribute like this :

```
Boolean latest;

public boolean isLatest() {
    return latest;
}

public void setLatest(boolean latest) {
    this.latest = latest;
}
```

In database the attribute is bit type with true/false value.

I want to select products which have latest = true. My hql is:

> FROM Product WHERE latest = true

I also tried:

> FROM Product p WHERE p.isLatest is true
>
> FROM Product WHERE latest is true

But it's always return all products or failed. Is there any way to select the products which have latest attribute = true. Any help would be great.

Comment: I think it depends on how the boolean is stored. See this question for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1154833/461499

Comment: Just wandering if it works if you add `getLatest()` instead of `isLatest()` to your entity?

Comment: @Predrag isLatest() is standard notation for Boolean.

I'm not sure if it will be the problem, but you should not mix Boolean and boolean. Use Boolean if it can be null. If it cannot be null, use boolean.

Comment: This simply works (just tried on my project, `is true` and `= true` both work, with `isLatest()`), so it's got to be something small enough to be easily overlooked. Try changing the type from `Boolean` to `boolean`, since your getter and setter are using primitive boolean type.

Comment: Which database? @bradleyfitz: `is` is for boolean.

Comment: try this FROM Product WHERE latest = 1

Comment: @Aleksandr M Any database. Hibernate follows JavaBeans convention for properties and recognizes method names of the form getFoo, isFoo and setFoo

Comment: @bradleyfitz: That question was directed to OP. Your *isLatest() is standard notation for Boolean* is incorrect. And which database matters.

Answer (score 4):

When I ran into this, I was using JDBC on an Apache Derby database. I was trying to set the value of a boolean field and was trying "=true", "=1", etc. In the end, I used a named parameter as shown below and that's how I got my situation to work.

```
session.createQuery("SELECT something FROM Product WHERE latest = :latest").setBoolean("latest", Boolean.TRUE);
```

Hopefully this helps someone with a similar situation.