# @Convert doesn't work with Hibernate and QueryDSL

Tags: java, hibernate, querydsl

I have a table `Incidencia` with a CHAR (1 Byte) column `visiblemovil`. This column has 2 possible values: "S" or "N" (yes/no, si/no in Spanish) that I want convert to `boolean` using `@Convert` annotation. This is my code:

**Converter:**

```
@Converter
public class SiNoToBooleanConverter implements AttributeConverter<Boolean, String> {

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Boolean aBoolean) {
        return aBoolean ? "S" : "N";
    }

    @Override
    public Boolean convertToEntityAttribute(String s) {
        return "S".equals(s);
    }
}
```

**Entity:**

```
@FilterDef(name = "PREGINCIDENCIA_FILTRO_FECHA", parameters = @ParamDef(name = "ultimaFechaSinc", type = "date"))
@Entity
public class Incidencia {

    private List<Incidenciapreguntas> preguntasList;

    private Integer codincidencia;

    private String descripcion;

    private Double horasfinalizacion;

    @Convert(converter = SiNoToBooleanConverter.class)
    private Boolean visiblemovil;

    private boolean tieneDocumentacion;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "CODINCIDENCIA")
    public Integer getCodincidencia() {
        return codincidencia;
    }

    public void setCodincidencia(Integer codincidencia) {
        this.codincidencia = codincidencia;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "DESCRIPCION")
    public String getDescripcion() {
        return descripcion;
    }

    public void setDescripcion(String descripcion) {
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "incidencia")
    @Filter(name = "PREGINCIDENCIA_FILTRO_FECHA", condition = "FMODIFICACION > :ultimaFechaSinc OR FMODIFICACION IS NULL")
    public List<Incidenciapreguntas> getPreguntasList() {
        return preguntasList;
    }

    public void setPreguntasList(List<Incidenciapreguntas> preguntasList) {
        this.preguntasList = preguntasList;
    }

    @Transient
    public boolean isTieneDocumentacion() {
        return tieneDocumentacion;
    }

    public void setTieneDocumentacion(boolean tieneDocumentacion) {
        this.tieneDocumentacion = tieneDocumentacion;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Incidencia that = (Incidencia) o;

        if (codincidencia != null ? !codincidencia.equals(that.codincidencia) : that.codincidencia != null)
            return false;
        if (descripcion != null ? !descripcion.equals(that.descripcion) : that.descripcion != null) return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = codincidencia != null ? codincidencia.hashCode() : 0;
        result = 31 * result + (descripcion != null ? descripcion.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "HORASFINALIZACION")
    public Double getHorasfinalizacion() {
        return horasfinalizacion;
    }

    public void setHorasfinalizacion(Double horasfinalizacion) {
        this.horasfinalizacion = horasfinalizacion;
    }

//    @Basic
    @Column(name = "VISIBLEMOVIL")
    public Boolean getVisiblemovil() {
        return visiblemovil;
    }

    public void setVisiblemovil(Boolean visiblemovil) {
        this.visiblemovil = visiblemovil;
    }
}
```

When I execute a SELECT statement (with QueryDSL) I'm getting this error:

```
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Fail to convert to internal representation
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Fail to convert to internal representation
```

**Repository:**

```
@Repository
public class IncidenciasDAO extends BaseDAO {

      public List<Incidencia> getIncidencias() {
        QIncidencia qIncidencia = QIncidencia.incidencia;
        JPAQuery query = new JPAQuery(entityManager);
        List<Incidencia> incidencias = query.from(qIncidencia).list(qIncidencia);
        return incidencias;
    }
}
```

**Full stacktrace**

```
    org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Fallo al convertir a representación interna
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Fallo al convertir a representación interna
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1377)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1300)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:266)
    at com.mysema.query.jpa.impl.AbstractJPAQuery.getResultList(AbstractJPAQuery.java:222)
    at com.mysema.query.jpa.impl.AbstractJPAQuery.list(AbstractJPAQuery.java:274)
    at com.grupogimeno.senda.movbrigadas.daos.IncidenciasDAO.getIncidencias_aroundBody0(IncidenciasDAO.java:26)
    at com.grupogimeno.senda.movbrigadas.daos.IncidenciasDAO$AjcClosure1.run(IncidenciasDAO.java:1)
    at org.springframework.cache.aspectj.AbstractCacheAspect.ajc$around$org_springframework_cache_aspectj_AbstractCacheAspect$1$2bc714b5proceed(AbstractCacheAspect.aj:1)
    at org.springframework.cache.aspectj.AbstractCacheAspect$1.invoke(AbstractCacheAspect.aj:61)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:180)
    at org.springframework.cache.aspectj.AbstractCacheAspect.ajc$around$org_springframework_cache_aspectj_AbstractCacheAspect$1$2bc714b5(AbstractCacheAspect.aj:65)
    at com.grupogimeno.senda.movbrigadas.daos.IncidenciasDAO.getIncidencias(IncidenciasDAO.java:22)
    at com.grupogimeno.senda.movbrigadas.daos.IncidenciasDAO$$FastClassByCGLIB$$bd07b3a2.invoke(<generated>)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:191)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:689)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor$1.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:58)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:213)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:66)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:622)
    at com.grupogimeno.senda.movbrigadas.daos.IncidenciasDAO$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$4b7b3a28.getIncidencias(<generated>)
    at com.grupogimeno.senda.movbrigadas.services.IncidenciasService.getIncidencias(IncidenciasService.java:22)
    at com.grupogimeno.senda.movbrigadas.services.rest.IncidenciasResource.getIcidencias(IncidenciasResource.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)2015-03-10 10:53:05,785 WARN  org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 17059, SQLState: 99999
2015-03-10 10:53:05,792 ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Fallo al convertir a representación interna

org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Fallo al convertir a representación interna
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1480)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1411)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1360)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1350)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:538)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:716)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.grupogimeno.senda.commons.filters.BaseBasicAuthLoginFilter.doFilter(BaseBasicAuthLoginFilter.java:64)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:230)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Fallo al convertir a representación interna
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractResultSetProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractResultSetProxyHandler.java:108)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81)
    at $Proxy115.getBoolean(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BitTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(BitTypeDescriptor.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:269)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:265)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:238)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:357)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2705)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1544)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1476)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1376)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:643)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:853)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:292)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2381)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2367)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2197)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2192)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:470)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:355)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:195)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1248)
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:257)
    ... 61 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Fallo al convertir a representación interna
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.CharCommonAccessor.getBoolean(CharCommonAccessor.java:185)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCharAccessor.getBoolean(T4CCharAccessor.java:697)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.getBoolean(OracleResultSetImpl.java:640)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSet.getBoolean(OracleResultSet.java:386)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyResultSet.getBoolean(NewProxyResultSet.java:2391)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractResultSetProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractResultSetProxyHandler.java:104)
    ... 86 more
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Fallo al convertir a representación interna
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1377)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1300)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:266)
    at com.mysema.query.jpa.impl.AbstractJPAQuery.getResultList(AbstractJPAQuery.java:222)
    at com.mysema.query.jpa.impl.AbstractJPAQuery.list(AbstractJPAQuery.java:274)
    at com.grupogimeno.senda.movbrigadas.daos.IncidenciasDAO.getIncidencias_aroundBody0(IncidenciasDAO.java:26)
    at com.grupogimeno.senda.movbrigadas.daos.IncidenciasDAO$AjcClosure1.run(IncidenciasDAO.java:1)
    at org.springframework.cache.aspectj.AbstractCacheAspect.ajc$around$org_springframework_cache_aspectj_AbstractCacheAspect$1$2bc714b5proceed(AbstractCacheAspect.aj:1)
    at org.springframework.cache.aspectj.AbstractCacheAspect$1.invoke(AbstractCacheAspect.aj:61)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:180)
    at org.springframework.cache.aspectj.AbstractCacheAspect.ajc$around$org_springframework_cache_aspectj_AbstractCacheAspect$1$2bc714b5(AbstractCacheAspect.aj:65)
    at com.grupogimeno.senda.movbrigadas.daos.IncidenciasDAO.getIncidencias(IncidenciasDAO.java:22)
    at com.grupogimeno.senda.movbrigadas.daos.IncidenciasDAO$$FastClassByCGLIB$$bd07b3a2.invoke(<generated>)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:191)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:689)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor$1.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:58)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:213)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:66)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:622)
    at com.grupogimeno.senda.movbrigadas.daos.IncidenciasDAO$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$4b7b3a28.getIncidencias(<generated>)
    at com.grupogimeno.senda.movbrigadas.services.IncidenciasService.getIncidencias(IncidenciasService.java:22)
    at com.grupogimeno.senda.movbrigadas.services.rest.IncidenciasResource.getIcidencias(IncidenciasResource.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1480)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1411)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1360)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1350)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:538)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:716)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.grupogimeno.senda.commons.filters.BaseBasicAuthLoginFilter.doFilter(BaseBasicAuthLoginFilter.java:64)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:230)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Fallo al convertir a representación interna
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractResultSetProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractResultSetProxyHandler.java:108)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81)
    at $Proxy115.getBoolean(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BitTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(BitTypeDescriptor.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:269)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:265)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:238)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:357)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2705)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1544)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1476)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1376)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:643)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:853)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:292)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2381)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2367)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2197)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2192)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:470)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:355)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:195)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1248)
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:257)
    ... 61 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Fallo al convertir a representación interna
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.CharCommonAccessor.getBoolean(CharCommonAccessor.java:185)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCharAccessor.getBoolean(T4CCharAccessor.java:697)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.getBoolean(OracleResultSetImpl.java:640)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSet.getBoolean(OracleResultSet.java:386)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyResultSet.getBoolean(NewProxyResultSet.java:2391)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractResultSetProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractResultSetProxyHandler.java:104)
    ... 86 more
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to add autoApply attribute to the Converter to apply the converter to any supported type? So you will have @Converter(autoApply=true)

Comment: i have just tried it. Same error remains.

Comment: Can you please try to remove ```@Basic``` above your column? ```@Basic ```tells that an attribute is to be persisted and a standard mapping is to be used, so this can be an issue.

Comment: can you change the `Boolean.TRUE` to just `true` and `Boolean.FALSE` to just `false`? I have encountered an issue with that at some point in the past.

Comment: Querydsl JPA executes internally JPQL queries, so it looks more like a JPA configuration issue.

Comment: @bigdestroyer Could you post the full stacktrace? At least including the Querydsl and Hibernate parts.

Comment: I have posted the stacktrace

Comment: Looking at your stacktrace, I see that actual runtime exception is ```TransientObjectException```. See ```AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1377``` line.

```TransientObjectException``` occurs when you have an object which references another object that is transient and then flush the Session. Check your entity, not only this field, but others. Also if it is possible update your question with full entity.

Comment: I have updated the question with full entity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Instead of using `@Convert`, I have solved it by creating a custom type. This is the solution:

[Hibernate entities mapping: Retrieve VARCHAR as boolean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28851462/hibernate-entities-mapping-retrieve-varchar-as-boolean/29036192#29036192)

Thanks to `raminr`.

Answer (score 1):

Your converter looks correct. The only thing is the `@Basic` annotation from your mapping. By definition, `@Basic` tells that an attribute is going to be persisted and a standard mapping will be used, so this can be an issue (Also I don't see any strong reason to mix `@Basic` and `@Column` in your case).

```
@Column(name = "VISIBLE")
@Convert(converter = SiNoToBooleanConverter.class)
public Boolean getVisible() {
    return visiblemovil;
}
```

Note: I haven't tested, but should solve the problem. Worth to try also moving annotations into the field, instead of getter.

Comment: It still doesn't work! :( Maybe QueryDSL doesn't support this feature?

Comment: Thats odd. I just tried same kind of mapping and it worked. Some magic happens there. Can you try to put annotation above your field instead of getter?

Answer (score 1):

You placed your mapping annotation on the getter for the mapped field in your entity class.
According to chapter 2.3.1 of the [specification](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/persistence-2_0-final-spec.pdf), this leads to property-based access.

The specification states that only the getter should be annotated for the mapping. But perhaps that is not enough for the `@Convert` annotation?

You could try to annotate the field:

```java
@Entity
public class Incidencia {

    @Column(name = "VISIBLE")
    @Convert(converter = SiNoToBooleanConverter.class)
    private Boolean visible;

    //other fields

    public Boolean getVisible() {
        return visible;
    }

    public void setVisible(Boolean visible) {
        this.visible = visible;
    }

}
```

(I corrected the name of the variable/field in your getter/setter methods.)

Comment: Thanks for answer. I have already tried this and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

try below code snippets, if one of them worked you can achieve the goal without using any `converter` or `@convert`:

---

```
Expression<String> expr = new CaseBuilder()
    .when(incidencia.getVisible()).then("S")
    .otherwise("N");
```

---

```
query().from(incidencia).list(incidencia.visible.when(true).then("S").otherwise("N"));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I need to retrieve the entity with all its fields, including `visible` as boolean. Not only `visible` field.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try this:

```
@Column(name = "VISIBLEMOVIL")
@Convert(converter = SiNoToBooleanConverter.class)
private Boolean visiblemovil;

public Boolean getVisiblemovil() {
  return visiblemovil;
}
```

or if you prefer to put it in the getter:

```
private Boolean visiblemovil;

@Convert(converter = SiNoToBooleanConverter.class, attributeName = "visiblemovil")
public Boolean getVisiblemovil() {
  return visiblemovil;
}
```

On Your converter:

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class SiNoToBooleanConverter ...
```

Lastly check the data type specified on your database. Kindly post include it in the question as well so i can verify.
I remember encountering this error when mapping enum (in java) to tinyint(mysql) where my converter Y type is not integer.

Comment: I have just tried that and it still doesn't work. I have updated the question, the column type y database is char(1 byte).

Comment: The exception thrown does not just pertain to the fields where you have specified the converter. Please check the rest of the attributes as it may not have been properly mapped to the correct type as well.