# Spring Security UserDetails with Oracle

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm implementing the interface `UserDetails` that have some methods. All of them return a boolean, such as:

```
public boolean isAccountNonExpired();
```

In Oracle do not exists `BOOLEAN` type as SQL column table attribute, so i have to define this as `VARCHAR2(1)`.

I'm my class (that implements `UserDetails`) i've defined the field accountNonExpired as String (instead of boolean).

So, the isAccountNonExpired() is like this:

```
@Column(name = "Account_Non_Expired")
    @Override
    @XmlElement @JsonProperty
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired()
    {
        return new Boolean(this.accountNonExpired);
    }
```

When i try to execute login (and repository query the table), i get the following error:

```
HHH000123: IllegalArgumentException in class: it.dirimologistika.site.entities.UserPrincipal, setter method of property: accountNonExpired
HHH000091: Expected type: java.lang.String, actual value: java.lang.Boolean
```

How i have to rewrite this class (and implements this method) using a VARCHAR2(1) instead of BOOLEAN? This is natural in MySQL, but in Oracle.. ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a JPA / Hibernate question, it's not specific to spring security.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/22368268/2257772 for a pure JPA implementation or the other comments for the hibernate one.

You should change the tag / title of your question