# Using JPA AttributeConverter for Boolean Y/N field: "Unable to render boolean literal value"

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

I'm implementing the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22368268/26535) to convert a 'Y'/'N' column to a Boolean value:

```
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "ACTIVE_YN")
@Convert(converter = BooleanToStringConverter.class)
private Boolean active;
```

.. and:

```
@Converter
public class BooleanToStringConverter implements AttributeConverter<Boolean, String> {

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Boolean value) {
        return (value != null && value) ? "Y" : "N";
    }

    @Override
    public Boolean convertToEntityAttribute(String value) {
        return "Y".equals(value);
    }
}
```

The problem is that I can't seem to use boolean values in JPQL. The following code gives the error below:

```
@Query("select thing from MyThing thing where thing.id = :id and thing.active = true")
public MyThing findOneActive(@Param("id") ThingIdEnum id);
```

Error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract x.y.z.MyThing x.y.z.MyThingRepository.findOneActive(x.y.z.ThingIdEnum)!
...
Unable to render boolean literal value [select thing from MyThing thing where thing.id = :id and thing.active = true]
...
org.hibernate.type.descriptor.converter.AttributeConverterTypeAdapter cannot be cast to org.hibernate.type.LiteralType
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out, because this field is a varchar/char before conversion, the JPQL needs to treat it as a string. I'm not sure if there's a better way to do this but the following worked:

```
@Query("select thing from MyThing thing where thing.id = :id and thing.active = 'Y'")
public MyThing findOneActive(@Param("id") ThingIdEnum id);
```

Comment: There isn't. If the column in the database is a string it needs to be compared to a string in the where clause. And if you use boolean literal in the query string it won't convert it to string for you.