# custom mapping rule for JPA entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I want to set some entity rules for JPA entity mapping. Very simple example would be if have an entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "my_table")
public class {
   @Id
   private Integer id;
   private boolean flagged;
   ....

  }
```

my flagged value is String in db marked as Yes/null/No. I want my flagged value to be set as true if value null/yes. false otherwise. Is there any way to define this custom rule on bean mapping for JPA entities. This is a simple example, would need to use this for complex rules as well. Appreciate your help.

Thanks

Comment: I might be a having a brain fart moment, but cant come up with decent way to do this without making this very complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write your own converter. Use the code below as a start point and adapt to your use case

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "my_table")
public class Myclass{    

  @Convert(converter=BoolToString.class)
  private Boolean flagged;    
  ...
```

}

And the converter as:

```
  @Converter
  public class BoolToString implements AttributeConverter<Boolean, 
String> {
  @Override
  public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Boolean value) {
  if (value == null) return "-";
  else return value ? "Y" : "N";
 }

 @Override
 public Boolean convertToEntityAttribute(String value) {
  if (value.equals("-") return null;
  else if (value.equals("Y")) return true;
  else if (value.equals("N")) return false;
  else throw new IllegalStateException("Invalid boolean character: " + 
  value);
 }
```

[Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1154833/configure-hibernate-using-jpa-to-store-y-n-for-type-boolean-instead-of-0-1)

[Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1154833/configure-hibernate-using-jpa-to-store-y-n-for-type-boolean-instead-of-0-1)

Comment: Looks promising, will try it out and mark the answer if this works. Thanks.