# Hibernate Attribute Converter Integer and String

Tags: java, hibernate

I have `int id` of primary key in the hibernate entity and in the DTO object, I have same `int id` and `String encId` for encrypted primary key id. Every time when I transfer the entity to DTO using `BeanUtils.copyProperties()` to copy entity to DTO vise versa, in the next line I'm encrypt/decrypting and performing db operation.

Could you please help me how to use `AttributeConverter<Integer, String>` and to copy the bean I should only do `BeanUtils.copyProperties()` and no more enc/decrypt logic other than `AttributeConverter`. Please give me the sample snipet of Entity to DTO.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49499701/custom-mapping-rule-for-jpa-entity/49499874#49499874

Comment: Thank you Graciano. With the help of this reference link, I tried and it's working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

entity:

```java
@Entity
public class Book {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
  
    @Convert(converter = IntegerToStringConverter.class)
    private Integer span;
}
```

converter

```java
@Converter
public class IntegerToStringConverter
    implements AttributeConverter<Integer, String> {

     @Override
     public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Integer value) {
        
          try {
              return Integer.toString(number);
          } else {
              throw new IllegalStateException(
                     "Invalid number: " + value
              );
          }
     }
 
     @Override
     public Integer convertToEntityAttribute(String number) {

         try {
             return Integer.parseInt(number);   
         } catch(Exception e) {
             throw new IllegalStateException(
                 "Invalid number: " + value
             );
         }
     }

}
```

[here](https://github.com/techguy-bhushan/kickhibernate/tree/module-based/attributeconverter/src/main/java/com/kickhibernate/ac) is a running example