# Defaulting bit fields in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

I have a MSSQL legacy database which uses a **BIT,NULL** column to represent a Java Boolean. The column contains the values 0,1,NULL.

I'd like all the NULLs to be converted to FALSEs in Java but I don't want to add `if (x==null) {x=false}` to the start of every setter.

```
  private Boolean digital;

  @Column(name = "Digital", length = 1, nullable = true, columnDefinition = "bit")
  public void setDigital(Boolean digital) {
    if (digital == null) { digital = Boolean.FALSE; }
    this.digital = digital;
  }
```

I tried converting the type to a primitive boolean but hibernate complains that it can't convert a NULL to a primitive even though I have set the default in java.

```
  private boolean digital = false;

  @Column(name = "Digital", length = 1, nullable = false, columnDefinition = "bit")
  public boolean getDigital() {
    return digital;
  }
```

Ideally what I want is a primitive boolean type that returns true (for 1) or false (for 0 or NULL). Are there any options in hibernate to do this.

Comment: Are you able to run updates against the db to change the null values to false?

Comment: No, I'm not the only entity updating the database and null might mean something to someone else.

Comment: So really I just need the last sentence answering without getting into a discussion about all the other things I could do instead. It's a legacy system with weird rules like scoping around a business stage where columns have different meanings and values depending on blar.

Comment: In that case you should be able to write a custom JPA attribute converter to handle the (de)serialization for you. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22368268/3419894) should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks, if you put that in an answer, I'll accept it.